# App crashes at startup, KERNELBASE.dll, Exception Code e0434352

Tags: c#, .net, windows, crash, gac

My C# / WinForms app crashes at startup.
I went through several posts here that cover that topic but I wasn't able to solve the problem yet.

That is the error I get:

```
Problemsignature:
Problemeventname:   APPCRASH
Applicationname:    MyApp.exe
Applicationversion: 1.0.0.0
Applicationtimestamp:   5b4c47c9
Faultedmodulename:  KERNELBASE.dll
Faultedmoduleversion:   6.1.7601.24150
Faultedmoduletimestamp: 5b0cbc65
Exceptioncode:  e0434352
Exceptionoffset:    000000000001a06d
Operatingsystemversion: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
Location-ID:    1031
Additionalinformation 1:    367e
Additionalinformation 2:    367e805d0e7c1ec3f63b05bb5ce5c416
Additionalinformation 3:    5a60
Additionalinformation 4:    5a6090e598b447a9043f485266c8e273
```

I searched for more detailed logs and found this:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131762111243226835
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=6925141c-88e4-11e8-a994-000c2920c559
IntegratorReportIdentifier=6925141b-88e4-11e8-a994-000c2920c559
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Applicationname
Sig[0].Value=MyApp.exe
Sig[1].Name=Applicationversion
Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Applicationtimestamp
Sig[2].Value=5b4c47c9
Sig[3].Name=Faultedmodulename
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Faultedmoduleversion
Sig[4].Value=6.1.7601.24150
Sig[5].Name=Faultedmoduletimestamp
Sig[5].Value=5b0cbc65
Sig[6].Name=Exceptioncode
Sig[6].Value=e0434352
Sig[7].Name=Exceptionoffset
Sig[7].Value=000000000001a06d
DynamicSig[1].Name=Operatingsystemversion
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Location-ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1031
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additionalinformation 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=367e
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additionalinformation 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=367e805d0e7c1ec3f63b05bb5ce5c416
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additionalinformation 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=5a60
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additionalinformation 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=5a6090e598b447a9043f485266c8e273
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
UI[3]=MyApp stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can look online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Search online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Search for a solution online later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\PROGRA~2\Sophos\SOPHOS~1\SOPHOS~2.DLL
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\ccb48f84a5cca36e9b0205b6a65ee54a\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\tv_x64.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\4575f30d7b13f1377c287e162ba3147e\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Drawing\3b5c30aa581d90fd18f9593f9c842b6d\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Windows.Forms\7a911b66e6652a094625f0ce974dc434\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
FriendlyEventName=No longer functional
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=MyApp
AppPath=C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
```

However, that doesn't really help me. I've checked the startup of the app in debug mode (different machine) where I am able to run it and logged the loaded assemblies. I went over each assembly and checked whether it was available on the other machine. Everything was there, although some assemblies are not available in the GAC but in the apps directory.

I have no idea where to look now, thanks for your help!

Edit: I get this message in the event viewer:

```
Anwendung: MyApp.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: System.IO.FileLoadException
bei MyApp.Program.Main()
```

Is there a way to get more information which assembly is missing?

Comment: Could you translate the german texts into english? BTW, I would start adding some exception handling in the code to have actual code to debug

Comment: @bradbury9 sure, thanks

Comment: I would guess it's a problem with one of the assemblies is x86 vs x64 or the to be loaded assembly has a higher framework version.

Comment: Usually these type errors are caused by one of two reasons 1) You put code before the Initialize(); statement 2) There is something wrong with the Designer.cs file.  I usually fix these issues by commenting out sections  of the designer.cs file until I find root cause.

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved it. It was a dependency with the wrong version

Comment: If you solved your issue, then please either post an answer so that other people having similar issues can get some ideas where to look, or delete your question completely if you think that it is too specialized and won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by checking the versions of the referenced assembly. One third-party assembly had a minor update which I forgot to update in my clients folder.